# How do you traverse a 2D list in a column-major oder?

Tags: python, list, traversal

Ok, so I think I understand the basis of how to traverse a 2D list in a row-major order(pictured in the code) but how would I do it backwards(column-major oder) in order to access the columns in a more orderly fashion?

```python
for row in range(len(matrix)):
    for col in range(len(matrix[row])):
        print(matrix[row][col])
    print('\n')
```

Comment: Place the column first: `for col in range(len(matrix[0]))`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```py
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

# row-major order
for row in a:
    for x in row:
        print(x, end='')
    print()
# 123
# 456
# 789

# row-major order
for col in zip(*a):
    for x in col:
        print(x, end='')
    print()
# 123
# 456
# 789

# better (in my opnion):
for col in zip(*a):
    print(*col, sep=', ')
# 1, 4, 7
# 2, 5, 8
# 3, 6, 9
```